# how to expand shortened p tag text depends upon next p tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox

I have one row with width 400px, that contain two p tag. One is the company name and another one is the position name. That `p` tags are shortened using `text-overflow: ellipsis;` and `min-width`. This is working fine.

My question is:

1. If 2 `p` tags text is too long, then the 2 tags width need to be same
2. If first tag name is too long and 2nd tag is short, then 2nd tag take width of that text and 1st tag take maximum width.

```css
.flex-container-text {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
}

.position-name {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  max-width: 100px
}

.company-name {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 3;
  max-width: 100px
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container-text">
  <p class="position-name">Position Name Position Name</p>
  <p class="company-name">company Name</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're saying you want the same behavior for both elements, so I would suggest to define only one class. I added the red border so you can easily see the width of the elements. Adding width:auto and display:inline block tells the element to be as wide as it contents, up to the max width. You can now play around with the max-width.

```css
.flex-container-text {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
}

.flex-container-text p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  overflow:hidden;
  max-width: 150px;
  border:1px solid red;
  width:auto;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container-text">
  <p class="position-name">Position Name Position Name</p>
  <p class="company-name">company Name</p>
</div>
```